# How to find a max value

Tags: python, max

I am new to python, and am trying to learn it with newmans computational physics.
I was trying to make a program to solve one of the exercises.
It is to calculate the highest binding energy using an approximate formula . I made this program, to find the binding energy:

```
from numpy import *
Z=int(raw_input("What is the atomic number?"))
a1,a2,a3,a4 = 15.67,17.23,0.75,93.2
for A in range(Z, 3*Z):
    if A%2==1:
        a5=0
    elif A%2==0 and Z%2==0:
        a5=12.0
    elif A%2==0 and Z%2==1:
        a5=-12.0
    B=a1*A-a2*A**(2/3.0)-a3*Z**2/A**(1/3.0)-a4*(A-2*Z)**2/A+a5/A**(1/2.0)
    print B
```

My problem is finding the maximum value for B. I have tried using lists, arrays and the max function.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or so when using the `max` function?

Comment: Aside: `from numpy import *`: people new to Python definitely shouldn't do this because it can lead to obscure problems you won't recognize (basically, some functions behave differently.)  Do `import numpy as np` instead and then refer to `np.some_function` if you need to.

Comment: `B` doesn't really have a maximum value other than itself, because it's a single number that you overwrite with every iteration of the loop. If you want to compare multiple numbers, save them in a structure like a `list`.

Comment: Yes, I get type errors.

Comment: How did u use the `max` function?...Can u post a code example of yours?

Comment: Yes, I realize this, because if I copy the output and save it as a list, then using the max function I get the desired output. But how can I save it as a list without copy pasting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the `from numpy import *` unless you are using it elsewhere. Aside from that using a list works fine. To get the max just call max(B) as follows:

```
Z=int(raw_input("What is the atomic number?"))
a1,a2,a3,a4 = 15.67,17.23,0.75,93.2
B = []
for A in range(Z, 3*Z):
    if A%2==1:
        a5=0
    elif A%2==0 and Z%2==0:
        a5=12.0
    elif A%2==0 and Z%2==1:
        a5=-12.0
    num = a1*A-a2*A**(2/3.0)-a3*Z**2/A**(1/3.0)-a4*(A-2*Z)**2/A+a5/A**(1/2.0)
    print num
    B.append(num)

print max(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

put your code in a function `binding_energy`, taking `Z` as argument:

```
def binding_energy(Z):
    a1,a2,a3,a4 = 15.67,17.23,0.75,93.2
    for A in range(Z, 3*Z):
        if A%2==1:
            a5=0
        elif A%2==0 and Z%2==0:
            a5=12.0
        elif A%2==0 and Z%2==1:
            a5=-12.0
        B=a1*A-a2*A**(2/3.0)-a3*Z**2/A**(1/3.0)-a4*(A-2*Z)**2/A+a5/A**(1/2.0)
        yield B
```

then it will return a generator of the results, and you can use `max()` to get the maximum `B`:

```
>>> max(binding_energy(Z))
```

If you instead want to find out which value of `A` maximizes `B`, replace

```
yield B
```

with

```
yield (A, B)
```